# Showing the Dimension of a Linear subspace of a Code

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, coding-theory

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}^n_q$ be a linear code with the dimension $k$ and $G$ the generating matrix of $C$, in which no row disappears.

We define a linear subspace $T:=C\ \cap \{x:x_i=0\}$ with $i\in \{1,...,n\}$.

Show: $dim\ T =k-1$

I first started with looking at $T$ and what elements are in $T$.
I came to the conclusion that these are:

$T=\{(0,x_2,...,x_n)^T, (x_1,0,...,x_n)^T, ..., (x_1,x_2, ..., 0)^T\}$.

Since T is a linear subspace, then $(0,...,0)^T\in T$. The only elements that are not in $T$ are then $\{(x_1,...,x_n)^T:x_i \not= 0$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}\}$.

I am not sure if my conclusions are right, but if they are, I am not sure how this affects the $dim\ T$.

Comment: Consider the linear code $C \subset \mathbb F_2^3$ with codewords $\{000,100,001,101$ whose $2\times 3$ generator matrix is $$G=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0 &0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right].$$ No row of G disappears and yet the subset of codewords that have a $0$ in the 2nd position is just $C$ itself. Are you sure that it is not "no column of $G$ disappears"? (In that case, the result is true).   Of course, some people write codewords as column vectors in which case $G$ would be a $3\times 2$ matrix, but not you: your description of the set $T$ writes codewords as row vectors, not column vectors.

Comment: You are right, my formulation is bad. These are all Column Vectors, thus i forgot to put the transpose symbol. I am sitting still at this and can't figure out what is with $\{x:x_i=0\}$ meant. The zero vector or my formulation above.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the set $T$.  $i$ is a _fixed_ integer in $[1,n]$ and $\{x:x_i=0\}$ is the set of all vectors with a $0$ in the $i$-th coordinate, not the set of $n$ vectors that you show in your question.  Thus, $T = .C \cap \{x:x_i=0\}$ is the set of all _codewords_ that have a $0$ in the $i$-th coordinate. Your task is ti show that $T$ has $q^{k-1}$ codewords.

Comment: So then I wrote there only the vectors of $\{x:x_i =0\}$ ?  Since we have a fix entry with the zero does that mean that $T$ has $q^k-1$ codewords?

Comment: I ment $q^{k-1}$